# How do you properly map a list in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, java-8, mariadb

I'm trying to implement a config-database using MariaDB and Hibernate in Java. Let A be a Person who can have B Licenses. Each license b consists of a list of Cs (some object which holds a string and an int).

```
class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    List<B> bs;
}

class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
    List<C> bs;
}

class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "c_id")
    private long id;

    String blabla;
    int i;
}
```

I can get it to save, however I can not get it to update without leaving redundant fields when resaving the changed A (load A from database -> add B to A's Bs / add C to B's Cs -> save -> redundant fields stay in database).

What is the proper way to do this?
So far I tried using @ElementCollection, CascadeType.persist and orphanRemoval = true with no luck.

Comment: I think your definition for relation between `A` and `B` and also for `B` and `C` are incorrect. for relation between A and B define `@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")` in B side and use `mappedBy` in A side also for B and C relation.

Comment: Let's see the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs` generated by it.

Answer (score 0):

Add updatable false in @JoinColumn So it will not change child tables while saving parent

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id",updatable=false)
    List<B> bs;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id",updatable=false)
    List<C> bs;
```